# Blur effect does not fill the entire View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, blur

I have a View controller that features a full screen UIImageView. When the controller loads, I just set a blur effect over the whole screen. The content mode for the UIImageView is set to scaleAspectFill. I set the blur effect like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var previewImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
previewImage.image = userPhoto     
let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
blur.frame = self.view.bounds
previewImage.addSubview(blur)
}
```

when I test the app on an iPhone 6 I get this result:

[image: Iphone Screen Capture]

There's an offset on the right an I can't figure out why. The picture underneath if is properly full screened but I can get the blur effect to fit over it...

****EDITED****

I applied the blur effect to the VC's view directly and now it works just fine, but I'd like to know why it doesn't work when I add the subview to the UIImage View...

Comment: When you call this code? May be in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Yes, I call the code in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: try calling it in view will appear with frame instead of bounds

Comment: Same output, maybe it has something to do with the UIImageView itself. I used autoLayout to fix the constraints so the view takes the full screen, which resulted in constraints of 0 up and down and -20 on the left and right

Comment: the bounds of the view is correct but you're not adding it to the view but to previewImage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two possible problems here:

1. Views are not laid out on the `viewDidLoad` stage. In this case you can force them to layout manualy:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       ...
   }
   ```
2. You add subview to the `previewImage`, not to the root view. You must check your storyboard, or fix code:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        previewImage.image = userPhoto     
        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
        blur.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.insertSubview(blur, aboveSubview: previewImage)
    }
   ```

Comment: I want to add a form and text entries over the image, that is why I added the blur to the `previewImage` and not the root view. The blur is perfectly fitted with the second solution, but all my labels are blurred..

Comment: Ok, I understand. So you can put the blur between the image and labels. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **@kelin** answer. You can even add the blur effect above your image in the interface builder.Just search for `Visual Effect View with Blur` in the objects section in the interface builder. Then add the `Visual Effect View` view above your image. It is also fully customizable through `Attributes inspector`. That way you you make sure that the blur will occupy the entire screen. It is also cleaner from architecture perspective , you do not need to configure your view through code.

[image: See this example]